# The multiplication in xarray

Tags: python-3.x, multiplication, python-xarray

We konw that xarray handle data by labels. That is, adding two datasets or multiplying two datasets are operated under the same dimensions and coordinates. However, I have a problem about the shape of the result after xarray multiplication operation.

The code is shown as follow:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
a = xr.DataArray([0,1,2,3],dims=['x'],
                 coords={'x':[10,20,30,40]})
b = xr.DataArray(np.array([[0,1,2,3],[0,100,200,300]]),
                 dims=['y','x'],
                 coords={'y':['y1','y2'],'x':[10,20,30,40]})
print(a*b)
print(b*a)
```

The first result is

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4, y: 2)>
array([[  0,   0],
       [  1, 100],
       [  4, 400],
       [  9, 900]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 10 20 30 40
  * y        (y) <U2 'y1' 'y2'
```

The second result is

```
<xarray.DataArray (y: 2, x: 4)>
array([[  0,   1,   4,   9],
       [  0, 100, 400, 900]])
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) <U2 'y1' 'y2'
  * x        (x) int64 10 20 30 40
```

Actually, the first and second is equal because xarray is label-based, however, why the shape of first result is [4,2] and the second is [2,4]?
Anyone who can tell me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`(a*b.T)` and `(b.T*a)` both produce arrays with shape `[4,2]`

I believe this is because `b.T` changes the DataArray dimension order in `b` but not the Coordinate order.

Compare b with b.T:

```
print(b)
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (y: 2, x: 4)>
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  0, 100, 200, 300]])
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) <U2 'y1' 'y2'
  * x        (x) int64 10 20 30 40
```

```
print(b.T)
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4, y: 2)>
array([[  0,   0],
       [  1, 100],
       [  2, 200],
       [  3, 300]])
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) <U2 'y1' 'y2'
  * x        (x) int64 10 20 30 40
```